# Ruby Syntax error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Tags: ruby, default-parameters

I am trying to pass default parameters in the method but not able to do so till now.I have written a method with below signature.

```
def abc(a,b=22,c,d=55)
end
```

i am getting error for above code as "syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'".

If i replace  the above code with the code shown below then it works fine.

```
def abc(a,b=5,c)

end
```

what could be the reason for this??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, I think, is what happens when you pass different numbers of arguments.

```
abc(1,2,3,4)
a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4
```

Pretty clear what the assignment should be.

But, how could you possibly fail to set the second parameter?

Is this missing the second, or the fourth parameter? What gets the default?

```
abc(m, t, z)
```

How could I miss out the second parameter, and leave the third with a useful value - a parameter that doesn't get a default?

You should group the defaulting parameters together:

```
def abc(a=25, b=6, c, d)
```

or:

```
def abc(a, b, c=6, d=7)
```

and then the behaviour is more predictable.

You probably should be looking at an options hash, though. A much more flexible way to pass variable arguments and some neat methods to handle missing arguments.

Answer (score 5):

From the Ruby documentation on [Default Values](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Default+Values):

> Arguments may have default values:
>
> ```
> def add_values(a, b = 1)
>   a + b
> end
> ```
>
> The default value does not need to appear first, but arguments with
>   defaults must be grouped together. This is ok:
>
> ```
> def add_values(a = 1, b = 2, c)
>   a + b + c
> end
> ```
>
> This will raise a SyntaxError:
>
> ```
> def add_values(a = 1, b, c = 1)
>   a + b + c
> end
> ```

Comment: Out of curiosity I tested this in IRB and to add to your answer, I would strongly suggest that the OP use the practice of defining parameters with default values as the last argument in your method signiture. When doing it elsewhere it can lead to unexpected results from a user perspective.


    1.9.3-p547 :001 > def abc(a, b=22, c); puts "a:#{a}, b:#{b}, c:#{c}"; end
    1.9.3-p547 :004 > abc(10,20) #=> a:10, b:22, c:20
    1.9.3-p547 :005 > abc(1,2,3) #=> a:1, b:2, c:3

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix default/non-default arguments that way.

How is Ruby supposed to know what `abc(1,2,3)` means? Are you providing `a,b,c` or `a,c,d`? Which is getting a default, `b` or `d`?